# can't type [replace]

Tags: errors

I need to type some code in Latex, but when I type [replace] (as a part of the code) it says:

"Missing number, treated as zero"

Here is my minimal working example:

```
       \documentclass[]{report}
       \begin{document}
       \texttt{
       [some text]\\
       some other text\\
       [replace]\\
        blablabla\\
        }
       \end{document}
```

Any Help is appreciated :) Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: It's because of the square parenthesis after the double backslash. Try this:
`\documentclass{report}
       \begin{document}
       \texttt{
       [some text]\       some other text\\~
       [replace]\        blablabla\        }
       \end{document}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `[...]` after `\\` is read as an optional argument.  It can be used to specify more vertical space between the lines via e.g. `\\[12pt]`.  But here you do not want your text `[...]` read as an argument to the `\\` command, instead you need to tell LaTeX to take it easy with `\\\relax`:

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\texttt{
[some text]\\
some other text\\\relax
[replace]\\
blablabla\\
}

\end{document}
```

In genaral you should not be using `\\` to break lines on ordinary text.  A blank line will give a new paragraph.  `\\` is appropriate in environments such as `center` or `flushleft`.  For code examples the `verbatim` environment would be a better start:

```
\begin{verbatim}
[some text]
some other text
[replace]
blablabla
\end{verbatim}
```

Here the line breaks in your source are respected and you don't need `\\`.   More sophisticated code typesetting is provided by packages such as `listings`.